# SQLite: How to emulate POSITION function?

Tags: sqlite, position, locate

Is there way to emulate not supported functions like POSITION, LOCATE, INSTR in SQLite?

Comment: According to http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html, there is `INSTR` (and on my Linux installation of 3.7.15.2, indeed there is). Which version do you use?

Comment: I use SQLite3 integrated in PDO, PHP v5.3.5 which returns: "no such function: INSTR";

Comment: Is there an interface to register a (php,user-defined) function within sqlite? (For tclsqlite3, there is). This way you could add your own implementation of INSTR for use in sqlite.

Comment: Yes, where can I find the example of implementation of INSTR function?